# Haskell Array Index out of range

Tags: arrays, haskell, range

My code is pasted [here](http://hpaste.org/47460/haskell_array_index_out_of_ran). 
Below is my ghci debug session. I still don't understand why it has a range of (0, -193459561) when the 'len' binding is 90570.

```
*Main> :break 125
Breakpoint 4 activated at SVMCF.hs:125:13-86
*Main> :trace main
Stopped at SVMCF.hs:125:13-86
_result :: UA.Array Int [User] = _
len :: Int = 90570
rts :: [RTuple] = (1,1,5.0) : (1,2,3.0) : (1,3,4.0) : (1,4,3.0) :
                  (1,5,3.0) : ....
[SVMCF.hs:125:13-86] *Main> :lis
124      points :: A.Array Int [Int]
125      points = assert (len > 0) $ A.listArray (1::Int, len) $ map (\(u,i,r) -> [u,i]) rts
126      values :: UA.UArray Int Double
[SVMCF.hs:125:13-86] *Main> :ste
Stopped at SVMCF.hs:125:13-28
_result :: UA.Array Int [User] -> UA.Array Int [User] = _
len :: Int = 90570
[SVMCF.hs:125:13-28] *Main> :ste
Stopped at SVMCF.hs:125:21-27
_result :: Bool = _
len :: Int = 90570
[SVMCF.hs:125:21-27] *Main> :ste
Stopped at SVMCF.hs:125:32-86
_result :: UA.Array Int [User] = _
len :: Int = 90570
rts :: [RTuple] = (1,1,5.0) : (1,2,3.0) : (1,3,4.0) : (1,4,3.0) :
                  (1,5,3.0) : ....
[SVMCF.hs:125:32-86] *Main> :ste
Stopped at SVMCF.hs:125:32-56
_result :: [[User]] -> UA.Array Int [User] = _
len :: Int = 90570
[SVMCF.hs:125:32-56] *Main> :lis
124      points :: A.Array Int [Int]
125      points = assert (len > 0) $ A.listArray (1::Int, len) $ map (\(u,i,r) -> [u,i]) rts
126      values :: UA.UArray Int Double
[SVMCF.hs:125:32-56] *Main> len
90570
[SVMCF.hs:125:32-56] *Main> :ste
Stopped at SVMCF.hs:125:60-86
_result :: [[User]] = _
rts :: [RTuple] = (1,1,5.0) : (1,2,3.0) : (1,3,4.0) : (1,4,3.0) :
                  (1,5,3.0) : ....
[SVMCF.hs:125:60-86] *Main> :ste
*** Exception: Ix{Int}.index: Index (1) out of range ((1,-193459561))
```

Comment: This does look odd.  My first thought was some kind of arithmetic overflow.  Int is 32 bits on a 32 bit machine and 64 bits on a 64 bit machine.  What does maxBound :: Int evaluate to?  However I can't find any straightforward relationship between 90570 and -193459561

Comment: Can you also paste the test data (`ua.*`)? I assume that the `SVM` module comes from the `svm` package.

Comment: Yes, SVM modules comes from svm package, but I add parametric polymorphism to this module, so the code will fail to compile if you use the cabal svm package. The ua.* data are from the stadard movielens dataset, I had paste the ua.test in http://hpaste.org/47496/movielens_uatest, but ua.base is too large to be pasted. Can I send all my files to you through email?

Comment: If the second file is too large to be pasted, you can upload it to e.g. rapidshare. If the dataset in question is available online, you can just provide a link.

Comment: Well, I think ghc uses 31 bits and 63 bits respectively.  One bit for Garbage collection.  I could be mistaken though.

Comment: You are mistaken. GHC does use the full 32 and 64 bits, respectively.

Comment: At first I was like: http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/beginners/2011-June/007241.html ...But then I was like, Oh. That's you.

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the index out of range exception is not being caused in the expression that you think it is!

> Data.Array.listArray (1,-10) [2,3,4,5]

does not throw any exception, it just gives you an empty array. Also note the column numbers in the last debug message:

> Stopped at SVMCF.hs:125:60-86

60 to 86 is `map (\(u,i,r) -> [u,i]) rts` which doesn't obviously have any indexing going on in it: There's certainly none in map, nor in its first argument, and `rts` looks clean too as it comes straight from `ua.base` via Parsec.

Because Haskell is allowed to be fairly free with its evaluation order, it's possible that the exception is being thrown by a reduction in a completely different expression. Are you sure all the other things you're passing into SVM are set up correctly? In particular, given that you're using `Int`-indexed arrays, are you sure there's no integer overflow occurring in any array? Are any of your datasets, for example, 4101507735 or 8396475031 records long, because these overflow to -193459561 as `Int`).

Does the `:history` command in the GHCi debugger give you any more information?

Comment: You are right. Finally I found out that it is a Int index overflow, and the source is not in the code pasted here. Though I finally solve this problem, I think this experience make me think that it's hard to debug haskell code.